# Use scp to send a file to an IP from a file

Tags: scp

I need to send a file ( my_file.txt ) to an FTP Printer whose IP address is contained in another file ( printer_ip.txt ). This file contains only one IP address.

```
$ cat printer_ip.txt
10.111.22.333
```

What is the simple command I can use? Something like this?

```
$ scp  my_file.txt  |  cat printer_ip.txt
```

Comment: Tag with your OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is

```
$ scp my_file.txt $(cat printer_ip.txt)
```